# minikube fowarding to a service

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a service that directs all traffic to a UI-pod. I want to redirect traffic from my localhost:80 to that service. 
I have tried :

```
kubectl port-forward my_service 6379:6379
```

This doesnt work because that service is actually supposed to be a pod. 
I have tried:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 --www=./local/www/
```

which looks for a pod too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately in kubernetes you can't port forward a service yet - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15180

However, in minikube, you can use ssh port forwarding for the VM to achieve the same result

`ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L 30000:localhost:30000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to expose a service through Minikube:

```bash
minikube service <my_service>
```

It will return the Kubernetes URL for the service in your local cluster. Reference for the [minikube service](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/service/) command.